# Restrict access to one user in tclhttpd server

Tags: .htaccess, webserver, tcl

I have a tclhttpd server and I want to restrict access to a particular user : say user X.
Reading through documenttstion, I found examples of restricting a folder access through htaccess file and specifying 'user require'.
But I don't want to keep it as a login page. Just for a user.
So my question is two fold :
a)  where can I add the user to whom I would like to give access.
b)  is there any other way I can implement this.

TIA

Comment: Suppose you are the web server and you receive a request. How do you know who made that request? If you need to identify a user, that user needs to authenticate himself. You could filter based on the request's IP address.

Comment: question also at SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/1251783/restrict-access-to-one-user-in-tclhttpd-server

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, it can be done using .tclaccess